# Ways to make shiny faster when using rhandsontable and reactiveValues

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming, rhandsontable

My shiny code has an rhandstontable that the user can edit. This leads to an update of the rightmost columns, based on a custom function. the code also plots values from the table on two ggplots, which also get updated when the table values change. All of this works except that **there is a funny double refresh that makes Shiny slow**; my table isn't big, about 50rows by 23 columns where only 4 columns are used in the plots but about 12 columns go into my custom function.

**Is there a way to make shiny faster using observe(), reactiveValues, or other related functions?**

I'm new at reactive expressions and I've been reading that it might be possible to make the app faster by caching data properly.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggrepel)

## Create the dataset
DF <- readRDS("data/DF2.Rds")
numberofrows <- nrow(DF)
# weighting variables
w1 = (c(4,3,1))
w2 = (c(1,1,1,1))
w3 = (c(2,2,1,2,1,1,2))
# Function to calculate scores
ScoresTbl <- function(data, w1, w2, w3){
  Description <- data[,1:9]
  Potential <- crossprod(t(data[,10:12]), w1)/sum(w1)
  Setting <- crossprod(t(data[,13:16]), w2)/sum(w2)
  Risk <- crossprod(t(data[,17:23]),w3)/sum(w3)
  data.frame(data[1:23],Potential,Setting,Risk) %>%
    mutate(
      SOP = rowMeans(data.frame(Potential,Setting,Risk)))
}

ui = fluidPage(
  fluidRow(column(12,
                  rHandsontableOutput('hotable1', width = "100%", height = "25%")#,
                  # actionButton("go", "Plot Update")
  )),
  fluidRow(column(6, plotOutput("plot1")),
           column(6, plotOutput("plot2")))
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  indat <- reactiveValues(data=ScoresTbl(DF,w1, w2, w3))

  observe({
    if(!is.null(input$hotable1))
      indat$data <- hot_to_r(input$hotable1)
  })


  output$hotable1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(ScoresTbl(indat$data,w1, w2, w3))
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = indat$data,
           aes(x=Potential,
               y=Setting, label = Project)) +
      geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
      scale_size(range = c(2,15)) +
      geom_text_repel(colour = "black",size = 2.5) +
      theme_minimal()
  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data = indat$data,
           aes(x=Potential,
               y=Setting, label = Project)) +
      geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
      scale_size(range = c(2,15)) +
      geom_text_repel(colour = "black",size = 2.5) +
      theme_minimal()
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```